# Chef's Kitchen tests fail but local examination prove otherwise

Tags: docker, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm testing two platforms, cento-7 & ubuntu-1604. Both converge successfully. But fail during verify.

### Ubuntu:

```
  System Package apache2
     ✔  should be installed
  Service apache2
     ×  should be running 
     expected that `Service apache2` is running
  Command curl localhost
     ✔  stdout should match /hello/i
     ✔  exit_status should eq 0
  Port 80
     ✔  should be listening
```

### Test Summary: 4 successful, 1 failure, 0 skipped

Seems strange that it fails on apache2 running but curl localhost succeeds.

I did a kitchen login

```
$ sudo systemctl status apache2
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

so I tried

```
$ ps -eo comm,etime,user | grep apache2
apache2            06:34:11 root
apache2            06:34:11 www-data
apache2            06:34:11 www-data
```

Looks like apache2 is running.

### Centos-7

```
  System Package httpd
     ✔  should be installed
  Service httpd
     ✔  should be running
  Command curl localhost
     ✔  stdout should match /hello/i
     ✔  exit_status should eq 0
  Port 80
     ×  should be listening
     expected `Port 80.listening?` to return true, got false
```

### Test Summary: 4 successful, 1 failure, 0 skipped

Strange that httpd is running and curl works but not listening on port 80?

So I logged in and ran netstat

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      562/httpd
```

### Here are my tests:

```
package_name =
  service_name =
    case os[:family]
    when 'redhat' then 'httpd'
    when 'debian' then 'apache2'
    end

describe package(package_name) do
  it { should be_installed }
end

describe service(service_name) do
  it { should be_running }
end

describe command('curl localhost') do
  its('stdout') { should match(/hello/i) }
  its('exit_status') { should eq 0 }
end

describe port(80) do
  it { should be_listening }
end
```

Here is my .kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: docker
  privileged: true

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-16.04
  - name: centos-7
    driver:
      platform: rhel
      run_command: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[hello_world_test::default]
      - recipe[hello_world_test::deps]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/integration/default
    attributes:
```

Any idea why I get the failures when it seems, to me at least, that on the test machines they are working as they should.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is because systemd is not set up in your Ubuntu platform. By default, kitchen-docker doesn't set up systemd support (as you can see with how you set it up for centos).

The second issue is more likely something funky with `ss`, which is the modern replacement for `netstat`. InSpec does have some fallback logic to use `netspec` but check out https://github.com/inspec/inspec/blob/8683c54510808462c7f3df6d92833aff3b21fe42/lib/resources/port.rb#L385-L421 and compare to your running container.

Comment: thanks coderanger.  if kitchen-docker doesn't set up systemd by default is there a setting to tell kitchen-docker to set it up?

Comment: oops- like I set it up for centos.  Thanks again,

Comment: Actually after unsuccessfully trying to get it working for ubuntu I switched to kitchen-dokken and upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.  Like this:   https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/blob/master/.kitchen.dokken.yml  everthing is working now like a charm :-)